# WinSNMP set source/manager port

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, port, snmp

The documentation for [SnmpSetPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa378246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that the api allows the port to be set for a destination entity.

However, is there a way to influence the port number of the source entity, ie. the manager? Or to at least configure it to use one port always?

By using wireshark I can see that the WinSNMP is selecting an arbritrary port src port. My client is using strict firewall rules. The SNMP SET are being sent out ok ( to agent port 161 ) but the responses are being blocked by the firewall rules. Since WinSNMP effectively is randomly selecting an outgoing port I cannot even configure the firewall.

**EDIT:** Added pics for illustration:

Outgoing request on src port 4089
[image: outgoing request]

Incoming response on same port 4089, which is of course blocked by firewall rules.
[image: incoming request]

Yet if I restart my application, WinSNMP allocates a different src port number eg. 4110

How can I control the src port of the request? ie. the response dst port.

Comment: Any half decent stateful firewall should be able to deal with this style of UDP request/response behavior. The WinSNMP API does not provide for specific port allocation because it doesn't care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random port (source port) is chosen from a port range reserved by Windows, and it is fully configurable,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851

By running `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport udp` and `netsh int ipv6 show dynamicport udp` you can see the current ranges.

The following commands can set the new ranges,

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=start_v4 num=number_v4
netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=start_v6 num=number_v6
```

But generally speaking you should change the firewall rules instead of changing manager side settings. Why should a firewall rule strictly check the source port? It is less obvious to me.

Comment: this affects all ephemeral port allocations, which could make the server perform poorly if the range is too small

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching at wrong place,

[Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959643.aspx)

SNMP uses the default UDP port 161 for general SNMP messages and UDP port 162 for SNMP trap messages. If these ports are being used by another protocol or service, you can change the settings by modifying the local Services file on the agent. The Services file is located in
            `\%SystemRoot%\System32\Drivers\Etc`

so go and change the port.

then you will be able to configure the port in firewall exceptions  :)

==========

## New Edits

Look at Ethernet II : in the images,Either SRC or DST is VMWARE_79

Now this openCore(4089) is port used by remote services / trojans/ and by default blocked by firewall due to its vulnerabilities, if you add the same port in firewall exceptions that should work.

(Note: this port will also not work in case accessed by some other services or remote code executions going on.)  but may lead to some insecurity, to avoid that you may allow to specific IP, CLIENT in this case.., if the port 161 is utilized by other application then also this may happen and it will look for some other port.

Also look for port 162 its used for trap [Ref.: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959637.aspx] (management system).

Check if the port 162 is blocked in client or your system then also this may happen and it will use the other port.

For more help I need more details on your project workings. Pls provide details if above edits does not help :)

Comment: WinSNMP is only using port 161 for the destination port, but the src port appears to be arbritrary. Since the src port is used in the response as the destination port it gets blocked.  See my edits above to clarify.

Comment: I think you are using VMware, that need some more work out on my side, will reply later on this :) I hope its fine by you :)